# Array of Pointer to Function Inside a Array Of Object

Tags: c++, arrays, function, class, pointers

I have a class Ghost that has an array of functions. This class Ghost is an
array too. How do I call the functions in main? I cant find a way to call this functions. I have seen some examples but nothing like this.

```
class Ghost;

typedef void(Ghost::* Func)();

class Ghost
{
    public:
    Func func;

    public:

    void init() {};
    void running_random() {};
    void running_afraid() {};
    void dead() {};


    Ghost(){
        func = new Func[5];

        func[0] = &Ghost::init;
        func[1] = &Ghost::random;
        func[2] = &Ghost::running_afraid;
        func[4] = &Ghost::dead;
    }

};


int main()
{
    Ghost ph[4];

    ph[0]->*func[0](); //???
    ph[0]->(*func[0]()); //???
    (ph[0]->*func[0])(); //???
}
```

Comment: The one thing missing is the actual error you're receiving.

Comment: `(ph[0].*ph[0].func[0])();` And btw, your `Func func;` is wrong. It should be `Func *func;` . Otherwise `func = new Func[5];` is nonsense. Also broken, there is no `Ghost::random`. That should be `Ghost::running_random`.

Comment: @OP -- I would suggest a public member function that calls the function via pointer.  `void call_func(int num) { (this->*func[num])(); }` -- Then it's just `ph[0].call_func(0);` in the `main()`.  Is that an option, i.e. adding a member function that makes the call look more pleasant?

Answer (score 1):

*"I have a class Ghost that has an array of functions"*

That isn't accurate. Those aren't just functions; they're pointers to *member* functions, which are distinct beasts unto their own.

Of the things wrong in this code.

1. **`Func func` should be `Func *func;`**

The way you had it, `Func func;` declares **a** single pointer-to-member variable, and you clearly want an array of them.

2. **Wrong member-access operator.**

You're using `operator ->*`, which should be used against a pointer to object married to a pointer to member. But you don't have a pointer to object. Given `Ghost ph[4];` that means `ph[0]` is not `Ghost*`, it's `Ghost`. Therefore, `operator .*` should be used.

3. **Improper access to `func` member.**

The array holding the pointers to members is a member of `Ghost`. Using the member access operators (`operator .*` or `operator ->*`) doesn't magically grant access to member `func`. That's just where you chose to store those member function pointers. Those operators don't behave like `operator .` and `operator ->`

4. **Incorrect object and member coupling.**

When coupling a pointer-to-member with a concrete object using `operator .*` (or a pointer to object using `operator ->*`), the full expression of the coupling should be enclosed in parentheses, *then* the argument list should follow in its own parentheses. In short, only the last of these makes sense (but is still broken due to the plethora of problems above).

```
ph[0]->*func[0]();
ph[0]->(*func[0]());
(ph[0]->*func[0])(); // closest to correct
```

**Summary**

After all of that, we can craft something that will actually work:

```
#include <iostream>

class Ghost;
typedef void(Ghost::*Func)();

class Ghost
{
public:
    Func* func;

public:

    void init() {std::cout << "here!!\n"; };
    void running_random() {};
    void running_afraid() {};
    void dead() {};

    Ghost(){
        func = new Func[5];

        func[0] = &Ghost::init;
        func[1] = &Ghost::running_random;
        func[2] = &Ghost::running_afraid;
        func[4] = &Ghost::dead;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Ghost ph[4];

    (ph[0].*ph[0].func[0])();
}
```

**Output**

```
here!!
```

I leave the ensuing memory leaks and realization this is probably not the architecture you really wanted in the first place for you to handle. But those were the problem, and *a* resolution, to the code you posted.